# Does _setSiteSpeedSampleRate work against visits, visitors, or pageviews?

Tags: google-analytics

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setSiteSpeedSampleRate):

> "Analytics restricts Site Speed collection hits for a single property
>   to the greater of 1% of visitors or 10K hits per day in order to
>   ensure an equitable distribution of system resources for this
>   feature."

Which of the following profiles would I `_gaq.push(['_setSiteSpeedSampleRate', 100]);` if I wanted to max out my data collection

1. 10,000 Pageviews, 5,000 Visits, 3,000 Visitors / Day
2. 20,000 Pageviews, 10,000 Visits, 8,000 Visitors / Day
3. 40,000 Pageviews, 15,000 Visits, 10,000 Visitors / Day

Conversely, what would you set `xyz` equal to in the following situation?

```
// Visits/Day: 725,000
// Unique Visitors/Day: 550,000
// Pageviews/Day: 6,000,000
_gaq.push(['_setSiteSpeedSampleRate', xyz]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

__setSiteSpeedSampleRate is passed with the __trackPageview.

```
1 = 100
2 = 50
3 = 25
```

Don't know if the function takes only integers, but you could pass 2 instead of the default 1 for Situation 4.
GA will cap at 1,6% of 6 Mln Pageviews (10k Pageviews), so higher than 2 (1,66 rounded up) certainly won't have an effect.